# Method Spoofing not working in Laravel POST -> PUT

Tags: php, laravel

Funny story, my Laravel routes are not working with the method spoofing... I have the following:

```
<form action="{{route('admin.page.update', $page->id)}}" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  <input type="text" name="page[name]">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This is rendered as:

```
<form action="http://ULTRA_HIDDEN_DOMAIN.dev/admin/page/9" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="ULTRA_HIDDEN_KEY">
  <input type="text" name="page[name]">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

But when I click on the submit button I get the following answer on Chrome Network:

`Request URL:http://ULTRA_HIDDEN_DOMAIN.dev/admin/page/9
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found`

When I do `php artisan route:list` I get it listed:

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                | Name                               | Action                                                            | Middleware     |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/page                         | admin.page.index                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@index                   | web,auth.admin |
|        | POST      | admin/page                         | admin.page.store                   | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@store                   | web,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/page/create                  | admin.page.create                  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@create                  | web,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/page/{page}                  | admin.page.show                    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@show                    | web,auth.admin |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/page/{page}                  | admin.page.update                  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@update                  | web,auth.admin |
|        | DELETE    | admin/page/{page}                  | admin.page.destroy                 | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@destroy                 | web,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/page/{page}/edit             | admin.page.edit                    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PageController@edit                    | web,auth.admin |
+--------+-----------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

The routes are created using `Route::resource('page', 'PageController');`.

Any thoughts on why the method spoofing is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code 302 in Http is for redirect, so I guess, this request is fine, but maybe it can't pass some middlewares you set, so forced to redirect to somewhere else.

For example, your PUT route need user logged in to update that record, and you didn't login so that middleware 'redirect' you to the login page with a 302 code.

Comment: Unfortunately I have checked the middleware and it's working correctly, I'm looking the problem with xdebug maybe something new arises :) thanks

Comment: Just for the documentation bug, the problem was that there was another request object on the controller, for example `public function update(Request $request, $id)` had `public function update(MyOwnRequest $request, $id)`. This new Request was the problem for the redirection.